# how to create manipulated new object from existing object with es6

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

I have to create `obj2` from `obj1`. `obj1` can have unlimited nested layers.
how can i create with es6 functions?

I tried `Object.keys(obj).forEach` etc. I'm not sure I understand. I am doing something wrong

I have this object (properties key has too many subkeys like Phone, Address etc.)

```
obj1 =  {
  type: "object",
  properties:{
    Person:{
      title:"",
      type:"object",
      properties:{
        Name:{
          type:"string",
          uiType:"input"
        },
        Surname:{
          type:"string",
          uiType:"input"
        },
      }
    },
    General:{
      title:"",
      type:"object",
      properties:{
        height:{
          type:"string",
          uiType:"number"
        }
        Nested:{
          title:'',
          type:'object',
          properties:{
            Nested1:{
              type:"string",
              uiType:"textarea"
            },
            Nested2:{
              type:"string",
              uiType:"textarea"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

And I need this

```
const obj2 = {
    Person:{
      Name:{
        type: "input"
      },
      Surname:{
        type: "input"
      }
    },
    General:{
      height:{
        type: "number"
      }
      Nested: {
        Nested1: {
          type: "textarea"
        },
        Nested2: {
          type: "textarea"
        }
      }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take an iterative and recursive approach while checking for objects.

```js
function build(source, target) {
    if (source.type === 'object') {
        Object.keys(source.properties).forEach(function (k) {
            build(source.properties[k], target[k] = {});
        });
    } else {
        target.type = source.uiType;
    }
    return target;
}

var object = { type: "object", properties: { Person: { title: "", type: "object", properties: { Name: { type: "string", uiType: "input" }, Surname: { type: "string", uiType: "input" }, } }, General: { title: "", type: "object", properties: { height: { type: "string", uiType: "number" }, Nested: { title: '', type: 'object', properties: { Nested1: { type: "string", uiType: "textarea" }, Nested2: { type: "string", uiType: "textarea" } } } } } } },
    result = build(object, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

With [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
function build(source) {
    return source.type === 'object'
        ? Object.keys(source.properties).reduce((r, k) => 
            Object.assign(r, { [k]: build(source.properties[k]) }),
            {})
        : { type: source.uiType };
}

var object = { type: "object", properties: { Person: { title: "", type: "object", properties: { Name: { type: "string", uiType: "input" }, Surname: { type: "string", uiType: "input" }, } }, General: { title: "", type: "object", properties: { height: { type: "string", uiType: "number" }, Nested: { title: '', type: 'object', properties: { Nested1: { type: "string", uiType: "textarea" }, Nested2: { type: "string", uiType: "textarea" } } } } } } };

console.log(build(object));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A bit smarter with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

```js
function build(source) {
    return source.type === 'object'
        ? Object.assign(
            ...Object.keys(source.properties).map(
                k => ({ [k]: build(source.properties[k]) })
            )
        )
        : { type: source.uiType };
}

var object = { type: "object", properties: { Person: { title: "", type: "object", properties: { Name: { type: "string", uiType: "input" }, Surname: { type: "string", uiType: "input" }, } }, General: { title: "", type: "object", properties: { height: { type: "string", uiType: "number" }, Nested: { title: '', type: 'object', properties: { Nested1: { type: "string", uiType: "textarea" }, Nested2: { type: "string", uiType: "textarea" } } } } } } };

console.log(build(object));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Could it be done using reduce instead of forEach?